# PHP Help with "if" statement to dynamically include files

Tags: php, dynamic, file, include

I have these files:

"id_1_1.php", "id_1_2.php", "id_1_3.php" etc
"id_2_1.php", "id_2_2.php", "id_2_3.php" etc

the number of files is not known because will always grow..

all the files are in same directory..

I want to make a if statement:

1. to include the files only if their name ends with "_1"
2. another function to load all the files that start with "id_1"

How can I do this? Thank you!

edit1: no the numbers will not be skipped, once I have another item for id_1_ collection of products I will add new ones as id_1_1, id_1_2 etc.. so no skipping..

Comment: Can numbers be skipped? EG can you have id_1_2.php and id_1_4.php but not have id_1_3.php?
Also are you only ever going to be looking for "1"s? Or might you want to find all of the id_2_X.php or id_X_3.php files and include them?

Comment: @aslum, if numbers could be skipped there wouldn't really be any easy way to know which files did exist without getting a list of all the files in the directory. I don't think that's the case.

Comment: If the files are being auto-generated into the same directory and will keep growing I strongly suggest you think about directory size limitations of filesystems.  You can only store a maximum number of files in a single directory.  Make sure you're going to scale within these limits ;)

Also, I can't know your exact situation but if these files are being auto-generated somewhere this is just as dangerous (if not more) than using `eval()`.

Comment: edit1: no the numbers will not be skipped, once I have another item for id_1_ collection of products I will add new ones as id_1_1, id_1_2 etc.. so no skipping..

each new item of the collection are just product color versions, so there will be about 4 or 5 per id_1_  id_2_  etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Each of these:
//   - scans the directory for all files
//   - checks each file
//   - for each file, does it match the pattern described
//   - if it does, expand the path
//   - include the file once

function includeFilesBeginningWith($dir, $str) {
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (strpos($file, $str) === 0) {
            $path = $dir . '/' . $file;
            include_once($path);
        }
    }
}

function includeFilesEndingWith($dir, $str) {
    $files = scandir($dir);
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        if (strpos(strrev($file), strrev($str)) === 0) {
            $path = $dir . '/' . $file;
            include_once($path);
        }
    }
}

/* To use: - the first parameter is ".",
   the current directory, you may want to
   change this */
includeFilesBeginningWith('.', 'id_1');
includeFilesEndingWith('.', '_1.php');
```

Comment: great explanation, really really precious for a novice like me.. 
muchas gracias senor :)

Comment: De nada! It was a helpful exercise for me as well, I used to do this with `exec` and doing an `ls` inside that. `scandir` is a much better starting point.

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_include($f, $s)
{
    @include_once("id_" . $f . "_" . $s . ".php");
}


function first_function($howmany = 100, $whatstart = '1')
{
    for ($i=1; $i <= $howmany; $i++)
    {
        my_include('1', $i)
    }
}

function second_function($howmany = 100, $whatend = '1')
{
    for ($i=1; $i <= $howmany; $i++)
    {
        my_include($i, '1');
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to make this start at 2 for both functions and check for id_1_1.php manually. Otherwise if you run both of these functions you will include 1_1 twice.

Comment: "the number of files is not known because will always grow.." - your code doesn't really do anything about this.

Comment: @aslum: this file was include only once.

Comment: @increditman: yes, i don't read it or this was be added in edit.

Answer (score 1):

Loosely based on Svisstack's original answer (untested):

```
function doIncludes($pre='',$post=''){
    for ($i=1;1;$i++)
        if (file_exists($str=$pre.$i.$post.'.php'))
            include($str);
        else
            return;
}

function first_function(){
    doIncludes('id_','_1');
}

function second_function(){
    doIncludes('id_1_');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will parse through every file incrementing by one until it finds a file that doesn't exist. Assuming contiguous numbers it should catch every existing file. If you want to include files with a number other then 1 in the name, just change $lookingfor as appropriate.

```
$lookingfor = 1;
$firstnum=1;
while ($firstnum>0) {
$secondnum=1;
  while ($secondnum>0) {
    $tempfilename = "id_".$firstnum."_".$secondnum.".php";
    if file_exists($tempfilename) {
      if (($firstnum==$lookingfor)||($secondnum==$lookingfor)) {include $tempfilename; }
      $secondnum++;
    } else {
    $secondnum=-1;
    }
  }
$firstnum++;
}
```